# Wiremock Mapping - use array in one of header values for one of the keys

Tags: java, arrays, wiremock

I want to make mapping for my wiremock server. However I have no idea how to map char array instead of string.

```
  "request": {
    "urlPathPattern": "/some/url",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers" : {
      "apiKey": {
        "equalTo": "test"
      }
    }

  }
```

This mapping will stub for string 'test' but i wanna match it to ["t","e","s","t"]
Putting it in that, ends up with initializationError -> equalTo operand must be a non-null string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WireMock uses regex matching, [so you can use the `matches` keyword](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#regular-expression) and a pipe character (`|`) to achieve this.

```js
{
  "request": {
    "urlPathPattern": "/some/url",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "apiKey": {
        "matches": "t|e|s|t"
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200
  }
}
```

[regex101's](https://regex101.com/) documentation on the `|` character:

> Matches either what is before the | or what is after it - in this case `a` or `b`.